# ffmpeg, creating thumbnail, but getting "deprecated pixel format used"

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails, scaling

I am trying to create thumbnails from my videos with ffmpeg, but I get the error "`deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly`", along with "`Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.`". I had a look around, but not sure what the new correct way of doing things is.

Currently my command-line call looks as follows:

```
infile=myfile.mp4
outfile=myfile.jpg
position=0
ffmpeg -ss ${position} -i "${infile}" -f image2 -vframes 1 -y "${outfile}"
```

I also tried (scales to 144px height):

```
ffmpeg -ss $position -i "${infile}" -y -filter_complex \    
  scale"=w=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:h=144[size0];[size0]split=1[screen0]" \
  -vframes 1 -map [screen0] "${outfile}"
```

Note: Using ffmpeg 3.1.3, via MacPorts, on MacOS X 10.11.6

Comment: what version of ffmpeg are you using?

Comment: It's just a warning. Video uses limited range, but JPEG uses full range. You can add `-color_range 2` if you'd like.

Comment: It's a warning, You could safely ignore it!